# Async.RunSynchronously in funscript

Tags: funscript

```
async {
       return "asd"
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This piece is throwing a compiler exception saying that

> "Could not compile expression: Call (None, RunSynchronously, [arg00,
>   NewUnionCase (None), NewUnionCase (None)])"

Is RunSynchronously not implemented in funscript compiler at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from the code example why `Async.RunSynchronously` is needed.

Only `Async.StartImmediate` is mapped at the moment.

This should be sufficient for most tasks. We didn't see the need to introduce a "blocking" method. JavaScript is executed on one thread. Therefore, there isn't any need for synchronization.

If you need to do something with the result of the asynchronous computation I suggest that you  push this inside the asynchronous workflow instead.